# Including node-neat + other files in node-sass grunt task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bourbon

I'm using grunt-sass and have been running into trouble using node-neat when adding additional include paths. When running...

```
  options: {
    includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths
  },
```

The sass task runs fine.

Though when I add another include file.

```
  options: {
    [
      require('node-neat').includePaths,
      '/assets/bower_components/_normalize.scss'
    ]
  },
```

I get an error *file to import not found or unreadable: "bourbon"*. So I added node-bourbon even though I think that is loaded by node-neat.

```
  options: {
    [
      require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
      require('node-neat').includePaths,
      '/assets/bower_components/_normalize.scss'
    ]
  },
```

I now get an error saying that *file to import not found or unreadable: "neat"*. I'm new to all of this and a little lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node-neat's `includePaths` property returns an array with both Bourbon and Neat's paths since Bourbon will be required. I would just concat the array like this:

```
options: {
  includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths.concat('/assets/bower_components/_normalize.scss')
},
```